# python data scraping getting "general"

Tags: python

[image]

i wanted to get reault like..
"in stock: xxx",
but i got "general" instead.

and it shows "Failed to read descriptor from node connection"

i dont know what's wrong with my codes.
thank you for help

[image]

i replaced the list with only one string, it also showed "general" and then "Failed to read descriptor from node connection"

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks, i've changed the code a bit, and it worked now~